# email address is not being parsed in beautifulsoup

Tags: django, beautifulsoup, python-3.5

I am scraping a webpage using the `beautifulsoup` and `requests` in `python3.5` . problem is when i tried to parse the email address in the `p` it gives me the `[email protected]`. I have tried the other links but no gain. cf_email tag is not even there. I am parsing through this

```
email_addresses=[]
for email_address in detail.findAll('p'):
   email_addresses.append(email_address.text)
   information = {}
   information['email'] = email_addresses
```

emails are in the `<p>` tags.

i have this html in inspecting element.

```
<div class="email">
   <p>test1@hotmail.com</p>
   <p>test2@yahoo.com</p>
   <p>test3@yahoo.com</p>
<div>
```

when i open the page source i have noticed this .

```
<p><a href="/cdn-cgi/l/email-protection" class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="472323222b2630262b2b26072f28332a262e2b6924282a">[email&#160;protected]</a></p>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample html?

Comment: you say you're parsing email addresses in `div` but you're going through `p`s in your code? By any chance is `detail` a div? Please add more details, and like @Rakesh said, can you add a sample html?

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: WYSIWYG. In html - text 'email protected', and in your result 'email protected'.

Comment: @crazyzubr sorry did not understand what you are saying

Comment: @fatpotato what result do you want to get? Attribute value data-cfemail?

Comment: no i want to get the email address. which is in `<p` tag if i inspect the element. but if i open page source it shows me the the html which i have posted in the question

Comment: @fatpotato so WYSIWYG. Yout html code not contains email, so get it will not work. I suspect that html code to contain email authorization on site is needed.

Comment: @crazyzubr it have emails i have updated the question please have a look

Comment: @fatpotato then code is needed as initialized *detail*. What version of beautifulsoup?

Comment: beautifulsoup 4 i am using.

Answer (score 0):

The page does not actually contain the email address. This is probably being done as a protection against spammers; there will be some javascript that replaces the holding text with the actual value.

In other words, the site is trying to stop people doing exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: it actually contains as i mentioned in the question there is difference between html on inspecting and on viewing page source.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I said. The page source does not contain the email. It is dynamically added to the DOM via Javascript.

Comment: @fatpotato Yes, because when you're using inspect element the js that replaces the tokens by the emails already ran. However when you're parsing with beautifulsoup, js doesn't get run, so you'll have to look for another way - or maybe not do it at all because the site doesn't seem to want you to.